# How to efficiently paginate with Firebase databases

Tags: firebase, pagination, nosql

I'm checking out Firebase as an option to host a database + a backend with an api for my web projects. Firebase offers two solutions as database, Cloud Firestore or Realtime Databse. Both of them are non sql db.

I always wonder how to efficiently paginate thousands, or million of records without the expense of having to fetch them all at once from the database and then split it based on your needs.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#node.js_2
This document seems to mention that for splitting the results you can either use a startAt/startAfter or endAt/endBefore methods, but referencing the record itself, not its position index among the results (with a predefined order)

So as I understand you first need to get all records, maybe in combination of the where method to filter, and the orderby to sort, in order to get the object reference you would stop or start counting at, and then use the limit method to narrow the results to the page size you would have.

If this is like this I have serious concerns about the memory usage of a backend application that needs to fetch from millions of records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pagination in Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore work on the basis of cursor or **anchor items**.

To read the first page, you create your query and then limit it to (say) 10 items.

To read the next page, you (re)create your query and then tell it to start at/after the last item of the first page, and return another 10 items.

While this may be different from offset-based pagination that you're used to, at no point does it read all nodes/documents.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification! Glad to know this wouldn't result on a performance overload!

Comment: Hello, then, with this aproach, we can't haver this kind of grid paginations: [firstPage, Page1, Page2, ..., PaneN, LastPage] 
https://static.vaadin.com/directory/user81301/screenshot/file6003104089062650335_1542621375989Screenshot2018-11-19at11.55.23.png